# Work done by force over curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, physics

Whew, gave this several shots. All attempts are wrong so here's where I'm at

$$F= ti + \frac{1}{8}j+k; C: r(t)=(e^{8t})i+(e^{8t})j+(-5t^2+t)k, -1\le{t}\le{1}$$
$$W=\int^b_a{\vec{f}\cdot\vec{dr}}$$
$$\frac{\vec{dr}}{dt}=(8e^{8t})i+(8e^{8t})j+(-10t+1)k$$
$$\vec{f}=ti+\frac{1}{8}j+k$$
$$\int^1_{-1}<t,\frac{1}{8},1>\cdot<8e^{8t},8e^{8t},(-10t+1)>dt$$
$$\int^1_{-1}8te^{8t}+e^{8t}-10t+1dt$$
$$8\int^1_{-1}te^{8t}dt+\int^1_{-1}e^{8t}dt+\int^1_{-1}-10tdt+\int^1_{-1}dt$$
$$\int{udv}=uv-\int{vdu}+C$$
$$u=t, dv=e^{8t}, du=1, v=\frac{e^{8t}}{8}$$
$$8\left[\frac{te^{8t}}{8}\Bigg|^1_{-1}-\int^1_{-1}{\frac{e^{8t}}{8}dt}\right]$$
$$8\left[\frac{te^{8t}}{8}\Bigg|^1_{-1}-\frac{1}{8}\int^1_{-1}{e^{8t}dt}\right]$$
$$8\left[\frac{te^{8t}}{8}-\frac{e^{8t}}{64}\Bigg|^1_{-1}\right]$$
$$8\left[\frac{te^{8t}}{8}-\frac{e^{8t}}{64}\Bigg|^1_{-1}=\frac{e^{8t}(8t-1)}{64}\Bigg|^1_{-1}\right]$$
$$8\left[\frac{e^{8t}(8t-1)}{64}\Bigg|^1_{-1}\right]+\int^1_{-1}e^{8t}dt+\int^1_{-1}-10tdt+\int^1_{-1}dt$$
$$\left[8\frac{e^{8t}(8t-1)}{64}+\frac{e^{8t}}{8}\right]\Bigg|^1_{-1}+\int^1_{-1}-10tdt+\int^1_{-1}dt$$
$$\left[8\frac{e^{8t}(8t-1)}{64}+\frac{e^{8t}}{8}+\frac{-10t^2}{2}\right]\Bigg|^1_{-1}+\int^1_{-1}dt$$
$$\left[8\frac{e^{8t}(8t-1)}{64}+\frac{e^{8t}}{8}+\frac{-10t^2}{2}+t\right]\Bigg|^1_{-1}$$
$$\left[\frac{e^{8t}(8t-1)}{8}+\frac{e^{8t}}{8}+\frac{-10t^2}{2}+t\right]\Bigg|^1_{-1}$$
$$\left[\frac{e^{8t}(8t-1)+e^{8t}}{8}+\frac{-10t^2}{2}+t\right]\Bigg|^1_{-1}$$
$$\left[\frac{e^{8t}(8t-1)+e^{8t}+4(-10t^2+2t)}{8}\right]\Bigg|^1_{-1}$$

The correct answer is:

$$W=e^8+e^{-8}+2$$

Comment: In the line
$$\frac{e^{8t}}{8}-\frac{e^{8t}}{64}\Bigg|^1_{-1}=\frac{e^{8t}(8t-1)}{64}\Bigg|^1_{-1}$$
where has the $t$ come from?

Comment: Whoops didn't see that fixed it

Comment: Whoops, fixed that too

Answer (score 0):

$$8\int^1_{-1}te^{8t}dt+\int^1_{-1}e^{8t}dt+\int^1_{-1}-10tdt+\int^1_{-1}dt\tag
 1$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1}te^{8t} = \frac{t}{8}e^{8t} - \frac{1}{8}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{8t}\tag 2$$

Put (2) in (1)

You get $=te^{8t}|_{-1}^{1} -\int_{-1}^{1}e^{8t}dt ++\int^1_{-1}e^{8t}dt -5t^2|_{-1}^{1} + 2$

Thus you get $$e^{8} + e^{-8}+2$$

The second term in the integration by parts cancels out with the second term of the overall integral and simplifies the process

Comment: How does the second term in the integration by parts cancel if it has a different coefficient of -1/8 and the overall integral is a coefficient of +1, edit: nevermind i forgot there was a scalar of 8 outside of the integration by parts

Comment: the 8 in front of (2) in (1) nullifies $\frac{1}{8}$.  Note carefully